Mean-reversion strategy with overnight gaps

When using stocks as time series data, it is common to encounter large overnight gaps, sometimes because of earnings, other times because of press releases. So, how to correctly account for this feature when checking for cointegration and calculating the z-score for mean reversion? Naively, even a simple triplet UNH-VST-COP would be having large returns out of sample, so I must be missing something here.
Edit: As suggested by @lehalle, below I've added the code which computes the weights using the Johansen method. Notice that (at least, according to my understanding), the Johansen method needs the close prices as inputs (not the returns).
On the other hand, the PnL is indeed computed as log return np.log(p[closeArrayName]).diff(). In these log returns, overnight gaps are present, hence my question. This is not an intraday strategy, in the sense that a position is opened at the close of a given day and held, classically, until it mean returns, which may occur several days later.
As data source, Yahoo finance (yfinance) was used and f in the code below is a Pandas dataframe file containing each individual ticker (for example, UHN.h5).

def assembleModelData(symbols, start, end, window, timeframe):

    """ Assembles the `modelData` dataframe. """

    closeArrayName = 'Adj Close'

    # start from empty
    modelData = pd.DataFrame()

    for s in symbols:

        # load
        p = pd.read_hdf(f, key = 'data')

        # select the time period
        p = p.loc[ start : end ]

        # compute log prices and stack side by side and rename columns appropriately
        modelData = pd.concat([modelData, pd.DataFrame({s: np.log(p[closeArrayName])})], ignore_index = False, axis = 1)

    # drop NaN
    modelData.dropna(inplace = True)

    return modelData


symbols = ['UNH', 'VST', 'COP']
start = '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
end = '2024-05-01 00:00:00'
timeframe = '1d'
window = 30

modelData = assembleModelData(symbols, start, end, window, timeframe)
for i in range(0, len(modelData) - window + 1):

        modelDataSub = modelData.iloc[i:window + i].copy()

        # cointegration test
        j = coint_johansen(modelDataSub, det_order = 0, k_ar_diff = 1)
        weights = list(j.evec.T[0] / j.evec.T[0][0])
```


Hi: It looks like you are using the open ? What about if you use each day's close ?

@markleeds thanks. I double checked, I'm using diff of log returns, close-on-close. Of note, total return is only 0.143 if using OLS to calculate the weights. Above, the Johansen method was used instead

Hi: Shouldn't close on close fix the overnight gap issue ? Who cares what's happening overnight if you're looking at closing prices. Once you're sure you're not having the gap behavior, then you can worry about the cointegration issues after that. The graph you showed shouldn't look like that if you're using close on close. Atleast I don't think it should.

Quanted: could you please document your question a little more. I do not see how to help: what is the formula that you use, and what is the chart you are showing us. Because I am like @markleeds : it seems obvious that your chart is intraday, so I do not understand how you "use diff of log returns, close-on-close"

If your strategy is based on intraday data, as in you look at the mean-reversion during the day, then you ignore (remove) the overnight returns. If it's based over several days, then you use end-of-day (eod) data and the jumps are "baked" into the data and won't cause issues with your statistical analysis.
Specifically, if your trading strategy is looking at 5-minute intervals throughout the day and your positions last only 5-minutes, then eod movement has 0 affect on your strategy - so its data can be removed. In this case, you would keep and calculate the returns from 09:30-16:30, but remove the returns from 16:30-9:30 (ignoring out-of-hour trading for simplicity). Thus, you would only have intraday returns.
Generally, there isn't a one size fits all approach to data cleaning. When you remove data, you lose information, but you should understand what information you're losing and how it will affect your results.
